# How to stop loop running out of memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, memory

I've come back to programming after a long haitus so please forgive any stupid errors/inefficient code.

I am creating an encryption program that uses the RSA method of encryption which involves finding the coprimes of numbers to generate a key. I am using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Egreenfie/gs2004/euclid.html) to generate highest common factors and then add the coprime to the list if HCF == 1. I generate two lists of coprimes for different numbers then compare to find coprimes in both sets. The basic code is below:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a,b=b,a%b
    return a


def coprimes(n):
    cp = []
    for i in range(1,n):
        if gcd(i, n) == 1:
            cp.append(i)
    print(cp)

def compare(n,m):
    a = coprimes(n)
    b = coprimes(m)
    c = []
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            c.append(i)
    print(c)
```

This code works perfectly for small numbers and gives me what I want but execution takes forever and is finally `Killed` when comupting for extremely large numbers in the billions range, which is necessary for even a moderate level of security.
I assume this is a memory issue but I cant work out how to do this in a non memory intensive way. I tried multiprocessing but that just made my computer unusable due to the amount of processes running.

**How can I calculate the coprimes of large numbers and then compare two sets of coprimes in an efficent and workable way?**

Comment: @ShadowRanger sorry mate didnt see those artifacts

Comment: If your code is really just printing out results, instead of returning the list - then print out each coprime as you find it, and drop the list entirely.

Comment: You're trying to find all coprime pairs from 1 to 6666666757? So O(6666666757^2) operations?

Comment: By the by, silly question: If `LargePrimeHere` is in fact prime, isn't *every* number that's not a multiple of `LargePrimeHere` coprime to `LargePrimeHere`? `LargePrimeHere`, if actually prime, has no factors besides `1` and itself, so it's coprime to anything that's not a multiple of `LargePrimeHere`. Trying to test and store 6.7 billion `int`s is going to be pretty time consuming, and insanely memory wasteful.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes that is the case, the gcd(prime, n) for all n < prime is always 1

Comment: @jasonharper no this is code coming out of a much larger script so printing is not what i need, i need a list to deal with later.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin: Yeah, I'm mostly trying to make sure they weren't incorrectly saying `LargePrimeHere` when they meant `LargeMaybePrime` or `LargeProductOfPrimes` or something else that wasn't really prime (where coprimality is pretty easy to define, no testing needed).

Comment: Also, side-note: Modern Python provides `math.gcd` that performs GCDs with optimized C code (in CPython anyway), which runs faster than anything you can implement by hand; you don't need to roll your own.

Comment: @Shadowranger yes sorry you guys are right, I incorrectly summarised my code. it actually is calculating coprimes of the multiple of two large primes, meaning that it will be A. a larger number and B. not prime itself.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I know it is an extremely large number of operations but the time it takes isnt really my issue here, its the amount of memory usage. I want to not have to load it all in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only thing you're worried about is running out of memory here you could use [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

```
def coprimes(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        if gcd(i, n) == 1:
            yield i
```

This way you can use the coprime value then discard it once you don't need it. However, nothing is going to change the fact your code is O(N^2) and will always perform slow for large primes. And this assumes Euclid's algorithm is constant time, which it is not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this basically saying cant have a list with all the coprimes as the list would exceed memory?

Comment: Yes, you have to either use and discard the values, or if you really need them, you can save them to disk, though I cant think of an application when you would need all these numbers at once.

Comment: What I really need is to compare two lists of coprimes generated for different numbers and then choose one that appears in both lists. For this I should write to file, because I can't have both lists existing in memory for me to work with yes? (sorry for the basic questions, i havent used generators before because im very new to 3.x

Comment: Yes, you would need to use disk for this if both lists exceeded memory size, in this case where you need the two complete lists to do a diff against, generators are not what you need.

Comment: I will edit the question to better suit the real problem. Thanks

Comment: @JonahFleming it might be worth asking a new one and give a more complete description of your problem

Comment: i guess you could loop one list into the other using genrator for each? What do you think @MitchelPaulin?

Comment: @NonoLondon you could, but that would be terribly inefficient as you would need to regenerate the list when you want to now compare the next number

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I've edited this one as i think the posts would end up as near duplicates but thanks for your help so far

Comment: "What I really need is to compare two lists of coprimes generated for different numbers and then choose one that appears in both lists." @JonahFleming, does this mean that you want to get items which are in both list?

Comment: @NonoLondon yes exactly. ive edited my question i hope that it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the strategy and approach this from the perspective of common prime factors.  The common coprimes between n and m will be all numbers that are not divisible by any of their common prime factors.

```
def primeFactors(N):
    p = 2
    while p*p<=N:
        count = 0
        while N%p == 0:
            count += 1
            N //= p
        if count: yield p
        p += 1 + (p&1)
    if N>1: yield N

import math
def compare2(n,m):
    # skip list for multiples of common prime factors
    skip = { p:p for p in primeFactors(math.gcd(n,m)) } 
    for x in range(1,min(m,n)):
        if x in skip:
            p = skip[x]                 # skip multiple of common prime
            m = x + p                   # determine next multiple to skip
            while m in skip: m += p     # for that prime
            skip[m] = p
        else:
            yield x                     # comon coprime of n and m
```

The performance is considerably better than matching lists of coprimes, especially on larger numbers:

```
from timeit import timeit

timeit(lambda:list(compare2(10**5,2*10**5)),number=1)
# 0.025 second

timeit(lambda:list(compare2(10**6,2*10**6)),number=1)
# 0.196 second

timeit(lambda:list(compare2(10**7,2*10**7)),number=1)
# 2.18 seconds

timeit(lambda:list(compare2(10**8,2*10**8)),number=1)
# 20.3 seconds

timeit(lambda:list(compare2(10**9,2*10**9)),number=1)
# 504 seconds
```

At some point, building lists of all the coprimes becomes a bottleneck and you should just use/process them as they come out of the generator (for example to count how many there are):

```
timeit(lambda:sum(1 for _ in compare2(10**9,2*10**9)),number=1)
# 341 seconds
```

Another way to approach this, which is somewhat slower than the prime factor approach but much simpler to code, would be to list coprimes of the gcd between n and m:

```
import math
def compare3(n,m):
    d = math.gcd(n,m)
    for c in range(1,min(n,m)):
        if math.gcd(c,d) == 1:
            yield c

timeit(lambda:list(compare3(10**6,2*10**6)),number=1)
# 0.28 second

timeit(lambda:list(compare3(10**7,2*10**7)),number=1)
# 2.84 seconds

timeit(lambda:list(compare3(10**8,2*10**8)),number=1)
# 30.8 seconds
```

Given that it uses no memory resource, it could be advantageous in some cases:

```
timeit(lambda:sum(1 for _ in compare3(10**9,2*10**9)),number=1)
# 326 seconds
```